# SQL query of distinct ID with sum

Tags: sql, ms-access, sum, distinct

So I'm not too sure how to phrase what I'm trying to do, so I'll just show it.

```
Serial_Number | Quantity
------------- | -------- 
      01      |    5    
      02      |    3
      02      |    3
      03      |    7
      03      |    2
```

I want the sum of quantity for each serial number. Such as

```
Serial_Number | Total_Quantity
------------- | -------------- 
      01      |    5    
      02      |    6
      03      |    9
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Hint:  `group by`, `sum()`.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh6sf9fs.aspx

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT Serial_Number , 
SUM(Quantity) as Total_Quantity
FROM tablename
GROUP BY Serial_Number ;
```

You should think this query step by step:- (while answering)

> 1. Like first you would group them to get the serial number one by one.
> 2. Now under one serial number you want to get the sum. if you google it...you will get to know of `sum`.

Comment: well, +1 for writing my exact query about 0.5 seconds before I clicked "Post"

Comment: @KobyDouek.: Thanks Koby...I was writing and then answered. As I saw no answer.